# Is there a way to get YouTube real time analytics API data?

Tags: rest, youtube, youtube-api, real-time-data

I'm wondering if is there a way to access YouTube real time analytics data like in your personal [analytics section.](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6096647?hl=en)

The [YouTube Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/data_model) doesn't mention anything about getting real time data, but I can see that some company like [SproutSocial](http://sproutsocial.com/insights/real-time-youtube-metrics/) seems able to show this data.

Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I was asking the exact same question!

Comment: @Massimiliano D'Elia Any progress in this? If so, please share the solution.

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli Unfortunately not, We stopped seeking for a solution months ago!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the YouTube API to get real-time data
It is listed here (the google developers YouTube api documentation): https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/
I’m guessing you’ll just have to make sure that the program or app you make will have to request the data every second...

Comment: It doesn't give realtime data, gives at least 2 day old data

Answer (score -2):

They're just requesting the data from youtube api. It's not real-time per se. They noted this in the section **How Real-Time Reporting Works**.

They're probably just requesting the data every hour and calculating the difference.

Comment: They are getting real-time statistics. It is clearly mentioned. See this line - "The first is available for a sliding window of two days (the last 48 hours) and the second is available for a sliding window of one hour (the last 60 minutes)."